# dll files not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I keep getting errors with AdaBoostTech.dll and RFRProgressTech.dll and it says the files cannot be copied.

[image: Picture of the Errors]

Comment: Did you check to see if the files are in that folder?

Comment: Well, your Visual Studio window shows that the files aren't there. Have you manually went to the directory to confirm the files exist?

Comment: The property screen in the bottom right... has Copy to Output Directory... set this to copy always and files should be included when they are copied down for latest changes to project

Comment: @Fuzzybear Your suggestion should make no difference.  Always copying them just makes build times longer.  Either the files are there or they aren't

Comment: I downloaded this from a GitHub and I cannot see the .dll files in that folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are obviously referenced by the csproj, but they don't exist in the folder specified.  Either the files were, but are no longer in your source code repository, or some manual process that puts them in that folder has not been performed, or, you deleted them by mistake (or possibly some overzealous IT anti-virus setting has deleted them).

Comment: Ya, that possibly it. I have found those files online and have downloaded them and put them in the folder and it seems to have work. Thank you!

Comment: Where have you found those files?  Are you sure they are the right ones for the project (i.e. the github tells you where to get them), or are they some 'random' files that just happen to have the same name, or possibly the right dll but wrong version etc?

Comment: They were in the Github from which I got the code but I when downloading the whole Github as a Zip to my computer and extracting the file it went missing so I downloaded it separately and it's running the program now.